# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have `mapView` of type `MKMapView` and some annotations in the map. I am trying to calculate the median of the latitude of this annotations using reduce, but I get an error claiming:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

Here is my code:

```
let medianLatitude = mapView.annotations.reduce( 0.0, { $0.coordinate.latitude + $1.coordinate.latitude })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `reduce`, the first parameter passed to the closure represents the partially accumulated result.

In your case, its type needs to match the initial value `0.0` -- it's `Double`.

So, try this:

```
let medianLatitude = mapView.annotations.reduce( 0.0, { $0 + $1.coordinate.latitude })
```