# Why does Swift's reduce function throw an error of 'Type of expression ambigious without more context' when all types are properly defined?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, immutability, higher-order-functions

```
var nums = [1,2,3]

let emptyArray : [Int] = []
let sum1 = nums.reduce(emptyArray){ $0.append($1)}
let sum2 = nums.reduce(emptyArray){ total, element in
    total.append(element)
}
let sum3 = nums.reduce(emptyArray){ total, element in
    return total.append(element)
}
```

For all three approaches I'm getting the following error:

> Type of expression ambiguous without more context

But looking at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) and the method signature of reduce:

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

You can see that both the `Result` and `Element` can be correctly inferred. Result is obviously of type `[Int]` and Element is of type `[Int]`.

So I'm not sure what's wrong. I also saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625947/type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context-in-swift-3) but that doesn't help either

Comment: Worth noting that "Type of expression ambigious without more context" is the 'catch-all' error the compiler gives when it knows the code isn't well formed, but has no idea why.

Comment: @Hamish That's good to know. But why is this assumed to be a not well-informed? Isn't it just %100 incorrect to mutate something which shouldn't be mutated? I don't understand why the compiler confused?!

Comment: @Hamish I've edited my answer as to why the compiler shouldn't really be confused. Because if it's written in a pure function format then it correctly spots the error!

Comment: Sorry, my last comment perhaps could have been clearer – I'm not saying the error you get is correct (you should get a mutability error instead), I'm saying that the error you are getting is the error the compiler gives when it cannot typecheck the code, but isn't able to pinpoint the exact cause of failure. Feel free to [file a bug over it](https://bugs.swift.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that you're passing the correct types to be inferred. **The error is misleading**.

Had you instead wrote:

```
func append<T>(_ element: T, to array: [T]) -> [T]{
    let newArray = array.append(element)
    return newArray
}
```

Then the compiler would have given the **correct** error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'array' is a 'let'
>   constant

So now we know what the correct error should have been:

That is both the Result and the Element are immutable within the closure. You have to think of it just like a normal `func add(a:Int, b:Int) -> Int` where `a` & `b` are both immutable.

If you want it to work you just need a temporary variable:

```
let sum1 = nums.reduce(emptyArray){
    let temp = $0
    temp.append($1)
    return temp
}
```

Also note that the following is **is wrong!**

```
let sum3 = nums.reduce(emptyArray){ total, element in
    var _total = total
    return _total.append(element)
}
```

**Why?**

Because the type of `_total.append(element)` is `Void` it's a function. Its type is *not* like the type of `5 + 3` ie `Int` or `[5] + [3]` ie [Int]

Hence you have to do:

```
let sum3 = nums.reduce(emptyArray){ total, element in
    var _total = total
    _total.append(element)
    return _total
}
```