# Does Swift offer any built-in function to return the result of appending to an immutable array?

Tags: arrays, swift, immutability, higher-order-functions

Writing the question and answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323529/why-does-swift-reduce-throw-an-error-of-type-of-expression-ambigious-without-mo/52323530#52323530), I'm curious to know if there is any simpler way to write the following:

```
var nums = [1,2,3]

let sum1 = nums.reduce([Int]()){
    let temp = $0
    temp.append($1)
    return temp
}
```

I know I can do:

```
var nums = [1,2,3]

let sum1 = nums.reduce([Int]()){
    return $0 + [$1]
}
```

But that comes off as a hack.

To explain this better, I want to get closer to the example (from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce)) below, just that it should be for an array:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let numberSum = numbers.reduce(0, { x, y in
    x + y
})
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since folks asked what was I trying to achieve:

I was doing the leetcode's [group Anagram's challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/description/).

My solution was:

```
struct WordTraits: Equatable{
    let count: Int
    let charactersSet: Set<Character>
}

struct Word: Equatable{
    let string: String
    let wordTraits: WordTraits
}


class Solution{

    func groupAnagrams(_ strs: [String]) -> [[String]]{

        var words : [Word] = []
        var answers : [(traits: WordTraits, words: [Word])] = []

        var count = 0
        strs.forEach{ str in
            count += 1
            let count = str.count
            let string = str
            let characterSet = Set(str)

            let wordTraits = WordTraits(count: count, charactersSet: characterSet)

            let word = Word(string: string, wordTraits: wordTraits)
            words.append(word)

        }
        while words.count != 0{
            let word = words[0]
            let traits = word.wordTraits
            var isWordAdded = false
            for (i, answer) in answers.enumerated(){
                if answer.traits == traits{
                    answers[i].words.append(word)
                    isWordAdded = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if !isWordAdded{
                answers.append((traits: traits, words:[word]))
            }
            words.removeFirst()
        }

        let emptyArray : [[String]] = []
        let finalAnswer = answers.reduce(emptyArray, { total, answer in
            let strings : [String] = answer.words.reduce([String](), {

                return $0 + [$1.string]
            })
            return total + [strings]
        })
        return finalAnswer
    }
}


let s = Solution()
print(s.groupAnagrams(["ate", "eta", "beta", "abet"])) // [["ate", "eta"], ["beta", "abet"]]
```

Comment: Why are you implementing `copying` with `reduce(..)`?

Comment: Are you looking for `reduce(into:)`? e.g `let sum1 = nums.reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1) }`. Though that's not actually doing any useful work – you'd get the same result with `let sum1 = nums`.

Comment: Why do you need another method when you know `+` completely works as expected?

Comment: @OOPer it seemed like a hack, but I think that was because I was slavishly trying to get it to work like the example from documentation. But usually such operators return when both lhs & rhs are of some type. I think I wasn't thinking clearly

Comment: It's not a hack (though, I do not know any clear definition of _hack_), but [clearly documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2963459). When one hand side is an Array and another is a Sequence of the same Element type, `+` returns an appended Array, you can rely on it.

Comment: @OOPer Worry not. There's a simple compiler transformation that optimizes `x = a + [b]` into `x = a; x.append(b)`. There's no array allocated to store the `[b]` array literal.

Comment: @Alexander Hey! I just retracted my vote to close. It's funny how many minor details I gathered by this silly question

Comment: @Honey What are you actually truing to achieve by doing array appends in a reduce?

Comment: @Alexander I've made an edit

Comment: @Honey And your solution doesn't quite work. You're grouping words that have the same sets of characters, and the same counts. That doesn't imply they're anagrams. E.g. `"aab", "baa"` are not anagrams, but are grouped by your algorithm. If you open a post on code review, or a chatroom, i'd be happy to help you out

Comment: @Alexander If the code doesn't work as intended, it's automatically off-topic for Code Review. Please take a look at [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I don't understand why `aab` and `baa` are not anagrams I thought anagram means to be able to have _same characters, only the order of characters can be different._ here. 1) both have a & b 2) same length 3) with different order  @Alexander

Comment: @Honey Oops, i made a typo, I meant `aab` and `abb`. They both only have the chars `a` and `b`, and both have length 3, so your code mistakenly categorizes them as anagrams.

Comment: @Alexander so then for my algorithm I need an nscountedSet...

Comment: This is a very poorly worded question. The title of the question is "Does Swift offer any built-in function to return the result of appending to an immutable array?" but that doesn't appear to be what you are asking.

Comment: @DuncanC The title is exactly what I'm asking. The edit was just a sidenote. Even though there are better answer which match the edited version of my question, I've not accepted them since I wanted to stay inline with the original question. I only made the edit to offer insight on what I was doing. FWIW your answer addressed the question and I upvoted minutes after it was written

Comment: @Honey Indeed. Or if not that, you can easily use a regular dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce(..)` has to know which type it is working with. To infer this it can use the return type or the type of the first argument. So you can also write:

```
var nums = [1,2,3]

let sum1: [Int] = nums.reduce([]){
    return $0 + [$1]
}
```

`[$1]` can't be replaced with `$1` because +-operator between value and collection is undefined.

Comment: What is the point of this use of the reduce command? It does a bunch of work and then returns an array identical to the source array. The subject of the OPs question makes it sound like the goal is to return the result of appending a single item to an immutable array.

Comment: @DuncanC I think it is about why the syntax has to be the way it is. Since it‘s no production code no harm done.

Comment: The title of this question was "Does Swift offer any built-in function to return the result of appending to an immutable array?" My answer provided a single-operator answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. But you can add it:

```
extension Array {
    func appending(_ newElement: Element) -> Array<Element> {
        return self + [newElement]
    }
    func appending(contentsOf sequence: Sequence) -> Array<Element> {
        return self + sequence
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Um, how about the `+` operator?

```
let nums = [1, 3, 5]
let more = nums + [7]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you didn't read the question completely. I'v mentioned what you did myself. But rethinking this, I think I'm being too picky...

Comment: My point is you don't need `reduce()` at all. Just add a one-element array to the previous array using the `+` operator as in my answer. All your variants are way, way too complicated.

Comment: True. This was just a high level of something I was working on.

Comment: Reduce will loop through the array, creating a whole series of temporary arrays and appending one more item each time. It will have `O(n)` performance, with a pretty large constant time for each of the n steps. (Memory allocations are pretty slow.) My solution should have `O(1)` performance, and it's a **lot** simpler to understand.

Comment: In case you were wondering what I was doing I made an edit to my question to include the real code...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to convert a complex structure to an array of arrays. You can use `map` for this.

This should work:

```
let finalAnswer = answers.map { answer in
    answer.words.map {
        $0.string
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I was able to solve it using minimal code:

```
class Solution {
    func groupAnagrams(_ words: [String]) -> [[String]] {
        let processedWords = words.map {
            (key: String($0.sorted()), value: $0)
        }

        return Dictionary(grouping: processedWords, by: { $0.key }).map { groupedValue in
            groupedValue.value.map {
                $0.value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I don't know why I usually start with reduce. This answer of yours provides a stark contrast between the two. I can't mark this as the accepted answer though. Since my question was initially just about the syntax. Otherwise this helped me the most

Comment: Nothing wrong with not accepting it. Btw, I added my solution :)

Comment: nice! I've never knew there `grouping:by:` init method. Nor I knew you can sort a `String` This is really fancy

Answer (score 1):

You've greatly overcomplicated your computation of "final answers". It could just be:

```
return answers.map { $0.words.map { $0.string } }
```